# condition not working as spect in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular9, angular10

I am trying to make condition using Angular 10 to check data with asp.net core 3 api is exist or not , but only put in if returning and post in else not working in below TS code

```
handleAddToCart() {
    let checking = this.CartService.getCartItemByItemId(this.productItem.itemLookupCode, this.cartForm.value.weight, this.productItem.storeId)
    .subscribe(c=>{
      return c;
    });
    if (checking ) {
      const updateCartPost = {
        itemID: this.productItem.itemID,
        itemLookupCode: this.productItem.itemLookupCode,
        categoryID: this.productItem.categoryID,
        departmentID: this.productItem.departmentID,
        itemDescription: this.productItem.itemDescription,
        subDescription3: this.productItem.subDescription3,
        quantity: this.cartForm.value.qty,
        weight: this.cartForm.value.weight,
        snapShotPrice: this.productItem.snapShotPrice,
        storeId: this.productItem.storeId,
        barcode: this.productItem.barcode,
        email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
        itemImage: ''
      }
      this.CartService.updateCartItem(updateCartPost).subscribe(u => {
        this.msg.sendMsg(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight));
        this.toaster.success('Added To Cart');
        console.log('sssssr');
      });

    }
else{
      this.CartService.addProductToCart(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight)).subscribe(() => {
        this.msg.sendMsg(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight));
        this.toaster.success('Added To Cart');
        console.log(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight));
      });
}
  }
```

Can any one help me?

I need to use condition with if and else but it returning only if and doesn't see else.

Comment: you can't return from an observable like that. Check the type of `checking`, it is actually `Subscription`. Look into piping with observables, in particular `switchMap` should be used here since you are chaining API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `checking` that you are checking for in your if condition will always be truthy because it is of type subscription. You are probably looking for this logic:

```
handleAddToCart() {
let checking = this.CartService.getCartItemByItemId(this.productItem.itemLookupCode, this.cartForm.value.weight, this.productItem.storeId)
.subscribe(c=>{
  if (c ) {
  const updateCartPost = {
    itemID: this.productItem.itemID,
    itemLookupCode: this.productItem.itemLookupCode,
    categoryID: this.productItem.categoryID,
    departmentID: this.productItem.departmentID,
    itemDescription: this.productItem.itemDescription,
    subDescription3: this.productItem.subDescription3,
    quantity: this.cartForm.value.qty,
    weight: this.cartForm.value.weight,
    snapShotPrice: this.productItem.snapShotPrice,
    storeId: this.productItem.storeId,
    barcode: this.productItem.barcode,
    email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
    itemImage: ''
  }
  this.CartService.updateCartItem(updateCartPost).subscribe(u => {
    this.msg.sendMsg(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight));
    this.toaster.success('Added To Cart');
    console.log('sssssr');
  });

}
else{
  this.CartService.addProductToCart(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight)).subscribe(() => {
    this.msg.sendMsg(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight));
    this.toaster.success('Added To Cart');
    console.log(this.AddToCart(this.cartForm.value.weight));
  });
}});}
```

Comment: thanks for reply @user2007130 but it doesn't exist in else every time entered in if only

Comment: @mohamed you need to verify the value of the variable 'c'. `if(c)` may not be the correct condition, it may be something more specific like `if(c === true)`.

Comment: yes thank you it solved by if(c == 'true');